# Uniformly Continuous on $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Stumped on a seemingly easy question, don't know why I can't think of a proof for this:

> Show that if $f\in C^1[a,b]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ must be uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Would a direct proof be sufficient for this question?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you proved earlier that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous?

Comment: While any continuous function $[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous, the assumption that it has a continuous derivative makes it easier to prove. Try proving that $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @AlvinLepik This is not a duplicate. Here we have the stronger assumption that the map is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you're right, mybad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Some cooking ingredients...

- A continuous map on a bounded interval is bounded. *I let you know to which map this should be applied*.
- The mean value theorem may be your friend.
- A lischitz map is uniformly continuous.

I let you use the ingredients for a good recipe.

Comment: i think i know what you mean, but do you mind providing some more context?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then exists $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq M, \forall x \in [a,b]$

Let $x,y \in [a,b], x<y$

By M.V.T on the interval $[x,y]$ exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$|f(y)-f(x)|=|f'(c)||x-y| \leq M|x-y|$$